# __unicode__() doesn't return a string

Tags: python

I have the following class in python

```
class myTest:
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.str = str

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.str
```

and in some other file a instantiate myTest to try out the unicode() method

```
import myClass


c = myClass.myTest("hello world")

print c
```

as print out I get `<myClass.myTest instance at 0x0235C8A0>` however if I overrider **__*str*__**() I will get `hello world` as output. My question is, how should I write the overrider for **__*unicode*__**() if I want it to output string instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally it is done like this:

```
class myTest:
    def __init__(self, str):
        self.str = str

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.str
    def __str__(self):        
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
```

This is because `__unicode__` is not called implicitly in they way that `__str__` and `__repr__` are.  It *is* called under the hood by the built-in function `unicode`, so if you don't define `__str__` you would have to do:

```
print unicode(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `print`, Python will look for an `__str__` method in your class. If it finds one, it will call it. If it does not, it will look for a `__repr__` method and call it. If it cannot find one, it will create an internal representation of your object,

Since you class does not define `__str__` neither `__repr__`, then Python creates its own string representation of the object. This is why `print c` displays `<myClass.myTest instance at 0x0235C8A0>`.

Now, if you want `__unicode__` to be called, you need to request a unicode version of your object, either by calling the [unicode built-in](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode):

```
unicode(c)
```

or by forcing your object to be represented as unicode:

```
print u"%s" % c
```