# Correct use of __repr__ and unicode in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have an object which contains among other, a title field in unicode. It has a `__unicode__` function that outputs that title:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title // e.g. u'\xe2'
```

Whenever I try to print a list of such objects, for example by simply referencing it in Jinja, I get:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` or similar. The problem doesn't happen if I print a single object.

I guessed it had something to do with `__repr__` not being defined. I defined it, as such:

```
def __repr__(self):
    s = u'%s' % self
    return s.encode('utf8')
```

Seemingly, the encode works and the function returns a str, but it still fails when Jinja tries to print the list of such objects, for example:

```
<small>{{ get_list_of_objects() }}</small>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Given that `__str__` is also apparently involved, could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: I added some details

Comment: Please re-read the linked help article and update accordingly.

Comment: Include your `__str__` as stated above and see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624264/unicode-doesnt-return-a-string#8624298).

Comment: Can you show the complete traceback?  Can you reproduce the error without Jinja (e.g., just by creating an instance of your class, putting it in a list, and then printing the list)?